# How to add childview programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, parent-child

I have googled for many days but don't find out. I just know how to do by IB, but not by programmatic way. I think `[addsubview:view]` is just only add sibling view, not parent-childview. Thanks guy for reading.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy:

```
//allocate a view (or take it from IB or from where you want)
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];

//add the view on the actual view (or any other view)
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

So this is a parent-child case and not a sibling view.

In fact by `[newView superView]` you get the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting confused by the difference between subviews and child view *controllers*, which are what's used when we have Container View Controllers that manage & display a number of child view controllers.

Take a look at the ["Implementing a Container View Controller" section of Apple's UIViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81), and you'll see how they describe how child view controllers work.

And, to answer your question specifically, here are the four methods that involve Child View Controllers (from the documentation):

> Here are the essential methods you might need to call:
>
> 1) addChildViewController:
>
> 2) removeFromParentViewController
>
> 3) willMoveToParentViewController:
>
> 4) didMoveToParentViewController:

And, of course, if you're *really* talking about subviews, there are a bunch of other people excitedly providing all sorts of answers to your question along this front.  Hopefully you'll have the correct answer for your problem really quick.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass a class to achieve this.

Example:

```
@interface MSCustomView:UIView
```

Here UIView is the parent class and MSCustomView is the child class

Answer (score 0):

The `[UIView addSubView:]` function adds a view as a child view to the view you call it on i.e

`[view1 addSubView:view2]` will add view2 as a child to view1.

In the Apple docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview:

Answer (score 0):

`addsubview` does just that. If you'll keep adding subviews to the same View you will basically create more siblings to that subview

**From the iOS Developer Library:**

> Views can embed other views and create sophisticated visual
>   hierarchies. This creates a parent-child relationship between the view
>   being embedded (known as the subview) and the parent view doing the
>   embedding (known as the superview).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Answer (score 0):

AddSubview add a view into parent hierarchy . IOS provide insertSubview too for ad child view. This

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html

provide a better approach to understand about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add sub view by [parentview addSubView:childView] in the syntax both  childView and parentview will be of UIView type.